# ASP.NET website deployment best practices resource suggestions

Tags: asp.net, deployment, resources

I have looked through the related questions, and none of them have provided me the information I am looking for.

Currently the team I work on does deployments of individual .aspx (and .aspx.vb) files for bug fixes/enhancments.  I am trying to affect change, as I really believe that deploying the "whole compiled site" is less error prone.  As this is a significant change from the way things have been done, my suggestions have ben met with significant resistance.

As my google-fu has not been up to par lately, I was hoping the SO community could either tell me that I am off my rocker, and that there is nothing wrong with moving individual files, or point me to some really good resources which would allow me to make a stronger case.

**Edit:**

This has all been great info, and reinforces the arguments that I have already been making, can anyone argue the other side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally to me rolling back immediately is most important. Again website projects are very hard when it comes to track the changes.

you can find a good detailed comparison [here](http://www.karpach.com/Web-site-projects-vs-Web-Application-projects-ASP-NET.htm). I am reproducing the article here.

1) Deployment. If you need in-place deployment, this model is perfect. However, it's not recommended since you are exposing your logic in clear text. So, anybody who have access to physical server can mess with your code and you never going to notice this. You can  try to make precompiled web site, but you going to end up with a lot of dll and almost untouchable aspx files. Microsoft recognized this limitation and released Web Deployment Project tool.

2) You need to keep track of what did you change locally and what did you upload to production server. There are no versioning control. Visual Studio has Web Copy tool, but this tool fails to help. I had to build my own tool, which kept track of changes based on Visual Source  Safe.

3) When you hit F5 for debug execution it takes merely 2 minutes to compile and execute whole project. Of course you can attach debugger to existing thread, but this is not an obvious solution.

4) If you ever try to generate controls on a fly  you will hit first unsolvable limitation. How to reference other pages and controls. Page and control compilation happens on a per directory basis. On best case you going to get assembly for each directory, in worst each page or control is going to get its own assembly.  If you need to reference another page from a control or another page you need to explicitly import it with the @Reference directive.

So for,

customControl = this.LoadControl("~/Controls/CustomUserControl.ascx") as CustomUserControl;

You need,

But what if you want to add something really dynamically and can't put all appropriate @Reference directives? Or What if you are creating server control and it doesn't have ascx file, so you don't have a place for @Reference ? Since each control has it's own assembly, it's almost impossible to do reflection.

Web Application Projects which re-appeared in Visual Studio 2005 SP1. They solves all issues mentioned above.

1) Deployment. You get just one dll per project. You can created redistributable packages and repeatable builds.You can have versioning and build scripts.

2) If you did code behind change you can upload just one dll. If you did aspx change you can upload just aspx change.

3) Execution takes 2-3 sec maximum.

4) Whole project is in one assembly, which helps reference any page or control. Conclusion. For any kind of serious work you should use Web Application Projects. Special thanks to Rick Strahl for his amazing article Compilation and Deployment in ASP.NET 2.0.

Comment: The Rick Strahl article: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp

Comment: Web Application Projects did not first appear in VS 2005 SP1. They were the main development model in VS 2003. After MS came out with the Website model, there was such a negative reaction from the developer community that they had to do a turn around and re-introduce it in the SP for VS 2005:
http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/01/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Deploying individual files for bug fixes and deployment is not a wise strategy. It sounds like you need a comprehensive build and deployment process. That doesn't mean it has to be complicated as there are some good tools available nowadays.

Build and deployment can get detailed, so as a minimum start try taking a look at the Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool). Install the tool on your build server and install it on your deployment server. Stage your ASP.NET content locally using the Visual Studio Publish command, then use the above tool to synchronize the entire package on the deployment server. I like this approach because it can be completely automated. When doing builds and deployments, aim for complete automation to reduce potential errors.

This is the bare minimum, but you will at least be certain that when specific files are changed, they are ALL synchronized on the deployment server.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rich.

Further information:

1. Deploying your SOURCE code ala the .vb files to the server is a BAD idea.  Compile it.  Obfuscate if you can, just don't deploy straight source.  Imagine an attacker which gains access to the system.  They could easily change your code and you might not ever notice.  Yes, you can use a tool like reflector to decompile.  But it's really hard to decompile a full site, make the changes you want, and put them back into production.
2. Deploying a single file might very well cause some type of problem in a related module.  I'm guessing you guys don't really do QA.  Tell them it's time to grow up.
3. Compiling your site will reduce JIT (just in time) compilation.  Think performance.
4. I'm also going to guess that pretty much everyone has production server access.  This is bad from the company's perspective as you have no controls in place.  What happens when an employee decides to cause some havoc before leaving?
5. What you are describing is inline with Cowboy coding.  Sure, it's fun to ride to the rescue but this style frequently blows everything up.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad for rolling back.  If you deploy as a web site vs web app, yeah you can do quick patches of one or two files, but what if you ever need to roll back to a previous version?  Good luck tracking down all the files that were updated to make the new version.  I much prefer the concept of a "version" for organizational reasons, and the compiled web app is much more inline with this than a "website" project.

Answer (score 0):

We had this dilemma and ended up going with the compiled version mainly for the security reasons.  If your site is external facing you could be compromising your security by allowing the vb files to be out there in plain text.  I realize one could still get your code if they really wanted to but it would be an additional hurdle they would need to go through.  If you use Visual Studio as your development environment you can publish the site pre-compiled and check the named assemblies option when publishing and this will essentially create a dll for each aspx page so you can do the one off page changes if necessary.  This was a great feature we found as we were constantly updating the whole site and there were times when things would get updated that shouldn't.  After using that feature we no longer had updates getting pushed that shouldn't.  As far as rolling back I hope your using some type of Source control / versioning system.  Team Foundation Server is great for versioning/source control but it is quite pricey.

Answer (score -1):

What is the best deployment strategy depends a lot on what kind of environment you are working in, and what kind of developers you are working with.

Visual artists that started with graphic layout and worked towards programming are much more in tune to individual page generation and release. Also the .aspx.vb files are simply server side scripting, not really programming.

Programmers usually start at the command line and branch out to environments such as the web and understandably feel that good programming practices should be applied too the web, including standard test and release cycles (and compiled code).

If the site is in constant flux the individual pages would make more sense, but if you are required to deliver an installation package to your production group msi files are the way to go, since they can be easily backed out if necessary.

If you evaluate what your groups needs are, which includes the varied experience of everyone in your group, you should be able to convince either yourself or the group. This is not a matter of which is better, but which provides the best business model.